# Понимание чего-то(,) как чего-то

Tags: орфография

Нужна ли запятая в данном обороте перед "как"? Под какое правило можно подвести этот случай?

Контекст:

> Я давно подхватил выражение: бодрят победы, а война быстро утомляет. Безусловно, фактор войны, а точнее - формы её протекания, - влияет на общественное сознание и общественные процессы. Тут важно отметить, что не просто характер боевых действий, но и понимание всего многообразия обстоятельств, связанных с войной, влияют на общество. И снова уточнение: не просто понимание, а понимание войны, как чего-то ясного, справедливого и неизбежного.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a comma here.

Rosenthal et al., *Справочник…*, §42.4.3:

> Сравнительный оборот с союзом *как* не выделяется запятыми:
>
> … если союз *как* имеет значение "в качестве" или сравнительный оборот с союзом *как* характеризует предмет лишь с одной стороны: *Богат, хорош собою, Ленский везде был принят как жених (П.); Итак, я вам советую как приятель быть осторожнее (Л.); Я говорю как литератор (М. Г.); Мы знаем Индию как страну древнейшей культуры; Я сохраню это письмо как память; Они разговаривают как чужие; Мы встретились как старые знакомые.*